# SQL: two different SUMs in the same query

Tags: sql

I am learning sql and today I tried to write two queries: one in which I calculate the total expenses in a certain year and another in which I calculate the total revenues. Here they are:

```
--We are interested in the Sum of actual Expenditures for the year 2020
--Grouped by Organization and Department
SELECT 
  O.OrganizationName, 
  D.DepartmentGroupName, 
  SUM(Amount) AS [Total Expenditures] 
FROM 
  FactFinance F 
  LEFT JOIN DimOrganization AS O ON F.OrganizationKey = O.OrganizationKey 
  LEFT JOIN DimDepartmentGroup AS D ON F.DepartmentGroupKey = D.DepartmentGroupKey 
  LEFT JOIN DimScenario AS S ON F.ScenarioKey = S.ScenarioKey 
  LEFT JOIN DimAccount AS A ON F.AccountKey = A.AccountKey 
WHERE 
  A.AccountType = 'Expenditures' 
  AND S.ScenarioName = 'Actual' 
  AND YEAR(Date) = 2020 
GROUP BY 
  O.OrganizationName, 
  D.DepartmentGroupName 
ORDER BY 
  O.OrganizationName 

--We are interested in the Sum of actual Revenues for the year 2020
--Grouped by Organization and Department
    SELECT 
      O.OrganizationName, 
      D.DepartmentGroupName, 
      SUM(Amount) AS [Total Revenues] 
    FROM 
      FactFinance F 
      LEFT JOIN DimOrganization AS O ON F.OrganizationKey = O.OrganizationKey 
      LEFT JOIN DimDepartmentGroup AS D ON F.DepartmentGroupKey = D.DepartmentGroupKey 
      LEFT JOIN DimScenario AS S ON F.ScenarioKey = S.ScenarioKey 
      LEFT JOIN DimAccount AS A ON F.AccountKey = A.AccountKey 
    WHERE 
      A.AccountType = 'Revenue' 
      AND S.ScenarioName = 'Actual' 
      AND YEAR(Date) = 2020 
    GROUP BY 
      O.OrganizationName, 
      D.DepartmentGroupName 
    ORDER BY 
      O.OrganizationName
```

Now I want to write a query where I can do all this at the same time (when I run it I want to have the two columns with the totals side by side to be clear). I tried writing one inside the other, but then the results are totally wrong:

```
SELECT O.OrganizationName, D.DepartmentGroupName, SUM(F1.Amount) AS [Total Expenditures], SUM(SUBQUERY.[Total Revenues]) AS [Total Revenues]
FROM
(
SELECT O.OrganizationName, D.DepartmentGroupName, F.Amount AS [Total Revenues]
FROM FactFinance F
      LEFT JOIN DimOrganization AS O ON F.OrganizationKey = O.OrganizationKey
      LEFT JOIN DimDepartmentGroup AS D ON F.DepartmentGroupKey = D.DepartmentGroupKey
      LEFT JOIN DimScenario AS S ON F.ScenarioKey = S.ScenarioKey
      LEFT JOIN DimAccount AS A ON F.AccountKey = A.AccountKey
WHERE A.AccountType = 'Revenue' AND S.ScenarioName = 'Actual' AND YEAR(Date) = 2020
GROUP BY O.OrganizationName, D.DepartmentGroupName, F.Amount
) AS SUBQUERY,
      FactFinance AS F1
      LEFT JOIN DimOrganization AS O ON F1.OrganizationKey = O.OrganizationKey
      LEFT JOIN DimDepartmentGroup AS D ON F1.DepartmentGroupKey = D.DepartmentGroupKey
      LEFT JOIN DimScenario AS S ON F1.ScenarioKey = S.ScenarioKey
      LEFT JOIN DimAccount AS A ON F1.AccountKey = A.AccountKey
WHERE A.AccountType = 'Expenditures' AND S.ScenarioName = 'Actual' AND YEAR(Date) = 2020
GROUP BY O.OrganizationName, D.DepartmentGroupName
```

Comment: Use sub-queries in the `select` portion, not the `from` portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Amount` is from `DimAccount` table a `SUMIF` approach would work.

```
SELECT
    O.OrganizationName,
    D.DepartmentGroupName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.AccountType = 'Revenue' THEN Amount END) AS [Total Revenues],
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.AccountType = 'Expenditures' THEN Amount END) AS [Total Expenditures]
FROM
    FactFinance F
    LEFT JOIN DimOrganization AS O ON F.OrganizationKey = O.OrganizationKey
    LEFT JOIN DimDepartmentGroup AS D ON F.DepartmentGroupKey = D.DepartmentGroupKey
    LEFT JOIN DimScenario AS S ON F.ScenarioKey = S.ScenarioKey
    LEFT JOIN DimAccount AS A ON F.AccountKey = A.AccountKey
WHERE
    S.ScenarioName = 'Actual'
  AND YEAR(Date) = 2020
GROUP BY
    O.OrganizationName,
    D.DepartmentGroupName
ORDER BY
    O.OrganizationName
```

Comment: I was so stuck on the subquery that I didn't think about the SUMIF! Thank you very much!